# Django-React/Redux-Apache project: Can't resolve url

Tags: django, reactjs, apache, redux, axios

first time building a web app. decided to use django/react with redux and django rest framework for api routing and component state. decided to implement apache as a production server and test locally. when I used the django development server everything worked fine but when I switched to apache I hit an issue.

I can get the static content to display at the root url "http://localhost" but can't get any further urls to resolve. On the main page of this app there's a component that, when it mounts, calls a url (GET) ".../api/buildings" to populate the component with some data but the server responds with a 404 or 500 but didn't when I used django dev server.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and seeing as I'm pretty new to this I'd appreciate some help!

here's some code references and lmk if I can provide anything else. thanks in advance!

building component that makes the call during mount:

```
export class Buildings extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        buildings: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        getBuildings: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        deleteBuildings: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getBuildings();
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <h2>Buildings</h2>
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Code</th>
                            <th>Last_Inspection</th>
                            <th />
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.props.buildings.map(b => (
                            <tr key={b.code}>
                                <td>{b.id}</td>
                                <td>{b.name}</td>
                                <td>{b.code}</td>
                                <td>{b.last_inspection}</td>
                                <td><button onClick={this.props.deleteBuildings.bind(this, b.id)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">delete</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    buildings: state.buildings.buildings
});

// gives access to this.props.deleteBuildings()
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getBuildings, deleteBuildings })(Buildings);
```

getBuilding action (axios call):

```
export const getBuildings = () => dispatch => {
    axios.get('/api/buildings/').then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_BUILDINGS,
            payload: res.data
        });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

urls.py for root dir:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('frontend.urls')),
    path('', include('buildings.urls'))
]
```

urls.py for "/api/buildings/":

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/buildings/', BuildingViewSet, 'buildings')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

apache config (default httpd.conf with this at the end):

```
# Django Project
LoadFile "a:/apps/python3/python38.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "a:/apps/python3/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp38-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "a:/apps/python3"
WSGIScriptAlias / "A:/stuff/projects/django_react/leadmanager/leadmanager/wsgi.py/"
WSGIPythonPath "A:/stuff/projects/django_react/leadmanager/"

<Directory "A:/stuff/projects/django_react/leadmanager/leadmanager/">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static/ "A:/stuff/projects/django_react/leadmanager/frontend/static/"
<Directory "A:/stuff/projects/django_react/leadmanager/frontend/static/">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uyei2iDA4Hs&t=404s

Comment: Show us the apache configuration

Comment: On your axios request where is your server ip?

Comment: just added the config. didn't have to add the server ip "localhost:80" to the request so right now I don't reference it in the request. lmk if that answers the question